# Compact data structures for JSON time-series data

Tags: javascript, json, data-structures, time-series

I'm looking to transmit multi-variate time-series data over a UART interface, ideally in plain text, to be ingested by some JavaScript. I'd like a compact representation (realise that is at odds with the plain text requirement), and am aware of [CJTSD](https://github.com/james-hu/cjtsd-js/wiki/Compact-JSON-Time-Series-Data) - but am wondering if there is anything even leaner (but still 'standard'), given that my data is sparse: *zero most of the time, and only one of the channels is non-zero at any one time*.

An example of data in CJTSD would be:

```
{
    "u": "s",
    "t": [1441000, 1441060, 1441120, 1441180, 1441240, 1441300],
    "a": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "b": [0, 1.1, 2.3, 0, 0, 0],
    "c": [0, 0, 0, 0, 1.4, 4.4],
    "d": [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "e": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
}
```

where t are timestamps (in seconds) and a, b, c, d and e are data points, measured at those timestamps.

Is there a more space-efficent representation?

Comment: What are these "channels" you mention? Why does your "x" array (meant to mean "maximum" according to CJTSD) have 0 as the first element while "m" (meant to mean "minimum") have 1 there? Why is "c" ("count") a floating-point number? To me it looks like you are using this CJTSD in a non-standard way which probably undermines the need for "standard". And I am not sure how standard that thing is, too.

Comment: Fair point - I had slightly corrupted the example data when adapting it for my purposes. I've updated the example data - its multi-variate i.e. it has a number of different variables measured together over a range of time points

Comment: Then I would go with { "unit": "minute", "start": 1441000, "offsets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "var": ["d", "b", "b", "c", "c"], "value": [1, 1.1, 2.3, 1.4, 4.4] }. You can certainly abbreviate those "unit", "start" etc to be one-letter names.